# Diamond-like interface constraints issue

Tags: typeclass, idris, theorem-proving, type-constraints

I've written an implementation of an `Applicative` and `VerifiedApplicative` for a pair with a monoid:

```
import Interfaces.Verified

VerifiedMonoid a => Applicative (Pair a) where
    (l, f) <*> (r, x) = (l <+> r, f x)
    pure x = (neutral, x)

VerifiedMonoid a => VerifiedApplicative (Pair a) where
    applicativeMap (l, x) g = sym $ cong {f=(\y => (y, g x))} (monoidNeutralIsNeutralR l)
    applicativeIdentity = ?h1
    applicativeComposition = ?h2
    applicativeHomomorphism = ?h3
    applicativeInterchange = ?h4
```

Although it compiles, if I weaken a condition on `a` in `Applicative` instance as follows:

```
Monoid a => Applicative (Pair a) where
    (l, f) <*> (r, x) = (l <+> r, f x)
    pure x = (neutral, x)
```

I see an error message complaining on `applicativeMap`:

```
When checking right hand side of Interfaces.Verified.Contravariant.Pair a implementation of Interfaces.Verified.VerifiedApplicative, method applicativeMap with expected type
        map g (l, x) = pure g <*> (l, x)

When checking an application of function Prelude.Basics.cong:
        Type mismatch between
                (<+>) {{constructor of Interfaces.Verified.VerifiedSemigroup#Semigroup a {{constructor of Interfaces.Verified.VerifiedMonoid#VerifiedSemigroup a}}}}
                      neutral
                      l =
                l (Type of monoidNeutralIsNeutralR l)
        and
                (<+>) {{constructor of Prelude.Algebra.Monoid#Semigroup ty {{constructor of Interfaces.Verified.VerifiedMonoid#Monoid a}}}} neutral l = l (Expected type)

        Specifically:
                Type mismatch between
                        (<+>) {{constructor of Interfaces.Verified.VerifiedSemigroup#Semigroup a {{constructor of Interfaces.Verified.VerifiedMonoid#VerifiedSemigroup a}}}}
                              neutral
                              l
                and
                        (<+>) {{constructor of Prelude.Algebra.Monoid#Semigroup ty {{constructor of Interfaces.Verified.VerifiedMonoid#Monoid a}}}}
                              neutral
                              l
```

Since it's shown `Semigroup ty`, apparently `Semigroup` instance is not inferred. I tried to write it explicitly as `(Semigroup a, VerifiedMonoid a) => VerifiedApplicative (Pair a)`, but it doesn't help.

Also it comes in mind a diamond inheritance issue, since `Semigroup => Monoid => VerifiedMonoid` and in the same time `Semigroup => VerifiedSemigroup => VerifiedMonoid`.

Any ideas how to workaround this? Limiting `Applicative` instance only on `VerifiedMonoid` is a bit awkward.